# What's the best way to show html reports generated by JasperReport in a jsp?

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, reporting, jasper-reports

I'm working on a reporting web application using JasperReports and Spring MVC.

Now, i need to show the reports generated by Jasper, inside a web page.

Is there some facility using Spring/JasperReport or i have to brutally include the html page into a jsp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Spring MVC supports jasper reports as view

- [Document](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/view.html#view-jasper-reports)

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to put on a test following this documentation. My doubt is: using the `ViewResolver` and specifying the `JasperReportsHtmlView` i have the report shown directly into the page or i have to download it?

Comment: You can do it both ways. if you want to make it downloadable you need to add header `Content-disposition: attachment`